# put and get json in ledger using go

Tags: json, go, blockchain

I am quite new to Go programming.

I am trying to insert a json into blockchain ledger and read it back using golang. My json looks like below:

```
var jsonBytes = []byte(`[{"FLD1":10,"Fld2":"ABC"}, {"FLD1":100,"Fld2":"0.26"}]`)
```

Ultimately, this json will be used as a look up table in my blockchain code.

1. what is the efficient format to store it in ledger? should I convert to string or keep that as a `[]byte`, considering that this json will be sent as a parameter from a client to chaincode. any examples about the data formats should be used in this scenario.
2. This json array would be big in size for ex., 1300 objects array. please suggest a format that is good enough to transfer this size.

Comment: [msgpack](https://msgpack.org/) test your data with this [online tool](https://toolslick.com/json-to-messagepack-converter), then good old [gzip or bzip2](https://golang.org/pkg/compress/)